# Error dialog with Android version 2.2

Tags: java, android, mysql, eclipse

I developed an Android application. It works fine in the phones having the version 4.4 but it shows the following error message when I run it on a phone having the version 2.2.

Could anyone help me on this please

```
   11-21 13:53:14.679: E/WindowManager(29791): Activity com.example.smart_survey.QR has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@406b9460 that was originally added here
11-21 13:53:14.679: E/WindowManager(29791): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.smart_survey.QR has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@406b9460 that was originally added here
11-21 13:53:14.679: E/WindowManager(29791):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:263)
11-21 13:53:14.679: E/WindowManager(29791):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:171)
11-21 13:53:14.679: E/WindowManager(29791):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:114)
11-21 13:53:14.679: E/WindowManager(29791):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
11-21 13:53:14.679: E/WindowManager(29791):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
11-21 13:53:14.679: E/WindowManager(29791):     at com.example.smart_survey.QR$Logs.onPreExecute(QR.java:362)
11-21 13:53:14.679: E/WindowManager(29791):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
11-21 13:53:14.679: E/WindowManager(29791):     at com.example.smart_survey.QR$UpdateScore.onPostExecute(QR.java:255)
11-21 13:53:14.679: E/WindowManager(29791):     at com.example.smart_survey.QR$UpdateScore.onPostExecute(QR.java:1)
11-21 13:53:14.679: E/WindowManager(29791):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
11-21 13:53:14.679: E/WindowManager(29791):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
11-21 13:53:14.679: E/WindowManager(29791):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
11-21 13:53:14.679: E/WindowManager(29791):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-21 13:53:14.679: E/WindowManager(29791):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-21 13:53:14.679: E/WindowManager(29791):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-21 13:53:14.679: E/WindowManager(29791):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-21 13:53:14.679: E/WindowManager(29791):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-21 13:53:14.679: E/WindowManager(29791):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
11-21 13:53:14.679: E/WindowManager(29791):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)

11-21 13:53:14.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29791): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-21 13:53:14.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29791): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
11-21 13:53:14.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29791):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:378)
11-21 13:53:14.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29791):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:223)
11-21 13:53:14.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29791):    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.removeView(Window.java:432)
11-21 13:53:14.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29791):    at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:278)
11-21 13:53:14.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29791):    at android.app.Dialog.access$000(Dialog.java:71)
11-21 13:53:14.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29791):    at android.app.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:111)
11-21 13:53:14.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29791):    at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:268)
11-21 13:53:14.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29791):    at com.example.smart_survey.QR$Logs.onPostExecute(QR.java:420)
11-21 13:53:14.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29791):    at com.example.smart_survey.QR$Logs.onPostExecute(QR.java:1)
11-21 13:53:14.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29791):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
11-21 13:53:14.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29791):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
11-21 13:53:14.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29791):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
11-21 13:53:14.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29791):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-21 13:53:14.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29791):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-21 13:53:14.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-21 13:53:14.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29791):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-21 13:53:14.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29791):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-21 13:53:14.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29791):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
11-21 13:53:14.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29791):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
11-21 13:53:14.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29791):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post some code please.

Answer (score 0):

**`pDialog = new ProgressDialog(QR.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);`**
**Put it in OnCreate method and simply call pDialog.show() in Preexecute and pDialog.dismiss() onPostExecute() and no need to change OnStop()**

Comment: i have changed the code as suggested but i still have the same error